# reflected or be reflected?

Tags: grammar

For this sentence, should I fill "reflected or is reflected"?

The importance of mythology within a culture **reflected** in the status of storyteller.

The importance of mythology within a culture **is reflected** in the status of storyteller.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: About active voice vs. passive voice, my general rule of thumb is inanimate things can't do any action by themselves. But there are lots of exceptions, e.g. *the sun shines*. Also, in proses and poems, I usually found that, quite often enough, many abstract things were be used as if they were a living thing.

Comment: @Damkerng It is transitivity of the verb, not animacy of the subject, which governs passivity.

Comment: @StoneyB When we want to have an abstract thought as the subject (e.g. *importance* in OP's sentence), isn't it a good idea to avoid active voice?

Comment: @DamkerngT. Not necessarily. We use passive to express an occurrence without mentioning the Agent, to order the Agent and Patient more conveniently for the flow of the argument, or to express a slightly different relationship between Agent and Patient. Any or all of these may be reflected in this example. OR This example may reflect any or all of these.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only the second one is correct. The first one has no finite verb so it is not a complete sentence. The second one could work if it were added onto another sentence

> This essay will explore **the importance of mythology within a culture reflected in the status of storyteller**.

but to stand alone it needs a conjugated verb.

Comment: + 0.75 It **could** be wrong in a different way: *reflected* could be a finite past form which either a) lacks a direct object or b) has an intrusive *in* before its direct object. Neither of those would make any sense, of course! :) - but I think the explanation needs to include reference to the distinction between past *reflected* and participial *reflected*; to the transitivity of *reflect* in this sense; and to the construction of passives with *BE* + passive participle.

Comment: In fact, I'm wondering  I should use passive voice ( is reflected) or active voice(reflected-finite-past tense) because I don't understand well about the meaning of this sentence.

Comment: @StoneyB: I'm not entirely sure "neither of those would make any sense" is strictly true. I can certainly say, for example, [the future reflects the past](https://www.google.co.uk/#q=%22the+future+reflects+the+past%22). So why shouldn't OP's first version be interpreted in the same way? Just because idiomatically we'd *tend* to include a "helper" verb ***is/was*** doesn't mean we're grammatically *obliged* to.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I intended that to be understood with specific reference to OP's first example -- it makes **no** sense to read 'reflected' in that sentence as intransitive (?The importance of mythology thought deeply?); it makes grammatical but not pragmatic sense to read it as transitive-active (?The importance of mythology derived from the status of the storyteller?), particularly given the second example, which means the exact opposite and *does* make pragmatic sense.

Comment: @StoneyB: I don't follow that. We're dealing with the matter of whether *A reflects in B* validly equals *B is reflected by A* (and it's not obvious to me it always matters whether it's expressed as *B reflects in A* when A and B are being metaphorically *equated* in this way). So assuming you're okay with *the image reflects in the mirror*, why can't we replace "the image" with "the importance", and "the mirror" with "the status"?

Comment: ...if that's too literal an example, how about "his selfishness [reflects in his behavior](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22home+life+reflects+in+his+behavior%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1)"?

Comment: @FumbleFingers "A reflects B" doesn't equate A and B, it ascribes A to B. And *reflects in* is not to my ear idiomatic. [Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=reflects+in%2Freflects&year_start=1800&year_end=2013&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%28reflects%20in%20/%20reflects%29%3B%2Cc00) concurs: *reflects in*:*reflects* peaks in 1920 at 2.27% and is now about 0.6%. That's random error/typo range. The percentages are even lower in BrE.

Comment: @StoneyB: I'm not saying it's a *common* usage. And to my mind OP's sentence would "mean" much the same thing if we swapped around the "importance" and "status" noun phrases (A and B can be seen as manifestations of the same underlying abstract property; alternatively we can suppose that either of them "flows from" or "is manifest by"). But if you don't see it the same way as me then I guess we just have to leave it there.